# How to count vehicles in a live video

Tags: vb.net, video-streaming

I am very new to images and video streams. I want to create a software that will count all the vehicles in a live video stream. I am using VB.NET and I don't even know where I should  start. What would you suggest I do and which libraries are supported to create such a application. I have heard about Emgu CV.

```
Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure
Imports Emgu.Util

Public Class MotionCountForm
    'From where should i start..
End Class
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to perform elimination of the background information. Moreover, I can give you a link that will give you a hint on how to start even though it is in MATLAB but you can get the concepts out of it and apply it using the programming language of your interest

[Start here even though it is in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.it/products/computer-vision/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/vision/videotrafficof.html)

and you can also look at this

[This will give you some hints](http://matlabnstuff.blogspot.ae/2013/02/vehicle-counting-system-in-matlab.html)

I suggest you to use openCV library, it can simplify your work

Answer (score 2):

There is a working example project on CodeProject that you can use to get you started:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257502/Creating-Your-First-EMGU-Image-Processing-Project

It is in c# but the basics are the same in any language